# Is there a way that a crashed Informix Trigger can write out a log?

Tags: triggers, informix

I have a trigger on a table in Informix 11.7 that writes to a log file all updates and deletes of a master data file.  The log file has a self-generating sequence number on it to prove that no records have been deleted from the log.  But if the trigger crashes for any reason, the sequence number does not roll back and a gap in the sequences appears making it look like logs have been deleted.  All I want to do is be made aware that the trigger crashed, so that I can explain the gaps in the sequence numbers.  But any file I write to gets rolled back and I don't think I can write to an ascii file from a trigger.  Can I make it write to the online.log or any other ascii file that doesn't get rolled back? or email that it has crashed?  Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably [create a RAW table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0509.htm) to hold the log records — or the messages.  A raw table is not subject to transactions; entries inserted are not rolled back even if the transaction that created the entry is rolled back.

I don't think an [external table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2053.htm) will help this time, but I stand to be proved wrong.

Comment: Tried this.  Worked perfectly with a raw table as the log table.  Many thanks for your help.